# Make child scope same as parent isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I would like to make a directive that has an isolated scope. 
Within this directive are some other directives and those should have the same scope as it parent.

```
<parent> <!-- Isolated scope --> 
  <child> </child> <!-- Belongs to the container isolated scope -->
</parent>
```

I'm not able to make this happen.

**Edit**

[this](http://plnkr.co/edit/XNg0YG6115dCfeqrZkyy?p=preview) Plunker shows how children keeps the same scope as it parent if parent is a child scope.  I forgot, when you don't use a template/templateUrl, data inside the element will not be thrown away.

It seems that children's scope can't be the same as parent scope if parent scope is isolated. Require is needed to add data to the parent scope.

Comment: You need to manually transclude. Here's a question I just answered recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32060662/968155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `require` property on your child directive definition object? You will need to define a controller on your parent and with the `require` property set to `^container` in the child directive you will then have access to the parent controller in your `link` function as the fourth argument:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.directive('container', function(){
  return {

    restrict : 'E',

    transclude : true,

    scope : {

    },

    template : 'container <ng-transclude> </ng-transclude>',

    controller: function($scope){
        // use this to add properties to the controller itself
        // which you can then access in the child directive
        this.container  = "container";
    },

    link : function($scope){

    } 
  };
})

.directive('child', function(){
  return {
    require: '^container',
    restrict : 'E',
    template : 'child container',

    link : function($scope, element, attrs, containerController){
      $scope.child  = "child";

      // logs: containerController Object {container: "container"}
      console.log('containerController', containerController); 
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Assuming you don't use `ng-transclude`, isn't there a way to make the parent scope the same as it children when the parent has an isolated scope?I made an updated plunker, where parent and children share the same scope. But I can only do that when they haven't an isolated scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of ngTransclude. In the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) it states:

> The transclude option changes the way scopes are nested. It makes it
>   so that the contents of a transcluded directive have whatever scope is
>   outside the directive, rather than whatever scope is on the inside. In
>   doing so, it gives the contents access to the outside scope.